# what console and splice do in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

During removing the data from the table I am passing index from the table, and I using it in a script.But I can't understand what `console.log(index)` and `$scope.facultymembers.splice(index, 1)` do?
Can anyone explain this?

```
$scope.removefaculty = function(index) {
  console.log(index);
  $scope.facultymembers.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: console.log logging things in browser console and for splice refer  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, x keeps its elements and y gets the sliced version console.log() is to just print the value what ever u print inside console it will display.

```
var x = [14, 3, 77];
var y = x.slice(1, 2);
console.log(x);          // [14, 3, 77]
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

*console.log(index)* is showing the index that you are removing at the debug console. Press F12 (on Chrome) to see the console.
*$scope.facultymembers.splice(index, 1)* is removing one element at *index* position. This function can do other operations, see javascript documentation for more information about this function: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp.

Answer (score 0):

console.log -It logs things you defined in it to a debug console.
splice -is a method to remove elements from array

```
$scope.facultymembers.splice(index,1);
```

will take take that index value u passed in function an removes the element from facultymembers array at that positon.
And '1' is nothing but how many elements to splice from array.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(index);` :  It's a object/method provided by debuggers that allows a script to log data to the JavaScript console. In simple words, here it'll log index value in console.

`$scope.facultymembers.splice(index, 1);` : This removed the first element after index value.

*Example:* var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]
fruits.splice(3, 1);
Output: Banana,Orange,Apple

Check snippet. You can understand.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add elements to the array.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction(3)">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

function myFunction(index) {
    console.log(index)
    fruits.splice(index, 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```